# Wordpress 6 click excerpt to show full post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to learn the new Wordpress 6 from  scratch.
In the custom theme index.php I can get the post title and the excerpt.

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile;
```

In the functions.php I followed online tutorial and created a new_excerpt_more() function, which will get the permalink of the post

```
function new_excerpt_more() {
     return '<a href="'. get_permalink() . '"> Read More...</a>';
    }
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

My issue is when I click the Read More... hyperlink, it doesn't show the full post content as I wanted. What is the simplest way to make the_excerpt() clikable and to show the full post content?
Rererence url:
http://ulike.vip/a/w

Comment: Hi I think check this out first.
Go to the Permalinks section and set the settings to the default and save

Comment: @Morteza Barati, it's newly installed and all settings at default, and it's not working locally either. The read more functions work in other official themes like twentytwentyone, but too complicated to undertand. I think it's because get_permalink() in the functions.php  will just take the page to index.php and which will in turn just show the_excerpt(). If I change the_excerpt() to the_content() the index.php will just show the full content not the excerpt. However, I don't have the knowledge and  skills to to get the right code to work.

Comment: In some cases it is likely to crash in htacsess which you can fix according to the above solution. (I recommend you try)

But if you are sure that everything is working properly do you have a single.php file?

Comment: @Morteza Barati,  I don't know what happened under the hood, but it worked after I created a single.php file in the theme folder. Thanks.

Comment: If the only file in your theme is index.php then you will only see all post excerpts. If you are linking to a single post, then make a single.php template.   Read the manual - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: @huyimin Hello , Please, thank you.
And thanks to HowardE for the info.
Yes, exactly, so you want to display the full information of a post when you click continue. You need to have a single.php file.

Comment: You should echo the permalink: 
`return '<a href="'. echo get_permalink() . '"> Read More...</a>';`